# Installing second windows service says service already exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-services

In VS 2013, I have a service installed on the development machine and it works well. I created another one today, but it won't install, saying the service already exists.

Let's call them Service A (old) and Service B (new)

I uninstalled Service A, then installed successfully Service B. Then tried to reinstall Service A but it says it already exists.

So whatever the combination, I can only install one service. I tried with Project Installer and InstallShield, both yeild the same result.

Any idea how to overcome that? If it's on any use, both services have some common dependencies (dll).

It is on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I turned it into an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So both your services must define the same value for `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceName` in the subclass that is in your service project.

Search for it in one of your service projects, and replace it with an alternative name.